# Googlebots Ignoring robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I have a site with the following robots.txt in the root:

```
User-agent: *
Disabled: /

User-agent: Googlebot 
Disabled: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
```

And pages within this site are getting scanned by Googlebots all day long.  Is there something wrong with my file or with Google?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be `Disallow:`, not `Disabled:`.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe give the [Google robots.txt checker](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35237) a try

Answer (score 2):

Google have an analysis tool for checking robots.txt entries, [read about it here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35237&ctx=sibling)

You might also want to check the IP addresses of the "rogue" robots to see if they really are owned by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Also I believe that the bot goes down the page and takes the first directive that applies to it. In your case, Googlebot and Googlebot-Image would never see their specific directives because they would respect the "User-Agent: *" first.

**Disregard this answer. I found information that points to this not being the case. The bot should find the directive specific to it and respect it**