# How to exclude my API from google indexing?

Tags: googlebot

OK, I have a website which has a series of buttons which call an api to return informtion relating to products.  The problem i have is that google is accessing and following the api every 10 minutes approximatley which means i am doing loads of lookups a day.

Can i stop google bots from doing this??

I have a robots.txt file and no follow meta but they do not seem to be doing much.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
   User-Agent: *
  Disallow:/index/
  Disallow /manufacturer/
```

I just noticed the pages didn't have extensions i.e manufacturer should be manufacturer.php

Comment: Did you see this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344697/googlebots-ignoring-robots-txt?rq=1

Comment: Please post your `robots.txt` file contents.

Comment: Also, kindly visit: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=35237&rd=1

Comment: thanks that's pretty much what my robot.txt says only with the disallow

Comment: Thanks Mike, i have read that, in fact thats where i wrote my robots.txt file from, but it hasn't stopped google from visiting

Answer (score 0):

[Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) will analyze your robots.txt for you and let you know what it is making out of it. I have found it very useful in the past. You can just paste your robots.txt and it will point out any flaws.

Failing that you can visit the [forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters).